# AWS Device Farm Error : 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium-android, aws-device-farm

I am trying to run my code in AWS device farm with the below capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                        driver =new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:" + "4723"+ "/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

I am getting below error

```
[DEVICEFARM] Setting up your device. This usually takes 2-3 minutes.
[DEVICEFARM] ########### Start executing testspec ###########


[DEVICEFARM] ########### Entering phase install ###########

[DeviceFarm] export APPIUM_VERSION=1.15.1
[DeviceFarm] avm $APPIUM_VERSION
/usr/bin/avm: line 261: appium: command not found
  [36m    exists[0m : [90m[0m
[DeviceFarm] ln -s /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/.bin/appium  /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js

[DEVICEFARM] ########### Entering phase pre_test ###########

[DeviceFarm] export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH/*
[DeviceFarm] export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH/dependency-jars/*
[DeviceFarm] echo "Start appium server"
Start appium server
[DeviceFarm] appium --log-timestamp --default-capabilities "{\"deviceName\": \"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_NAME\", \"platformName\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME\", \"app\":\"$DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH\", \"udid\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID\", \"platformVersion\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_OS_VERSION\", \"chromedriverExecutable\":\"$DEVICEFARM_CHROMEDRIVER_EXECUTABLE\"}" >> $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt 2>&1 &
[DeviceFarm] start_appium_timeout=0; while [ true ]; do
    if [ $start_appium_timeout -gt 60 ];
    then
        echo "appium server never started in 60 seconds. Exiting";
        exit 1;
    fi;
    grep -i "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723" $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt >> /dev/null 2>&1;
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];
    then
        echo "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723";
        break;
    else
        echo "Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second";
        sleep 1;
        start_appium_timeout=$((start_appium_timeout+1));
    fi;
done;
```

Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second
Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

```
[DEVICEFARM] ########### Entering phase test ###########

[DeviceFarm] echo "Navigate to test package directory"
Navigate to test package directory
[DeviceFarm] cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH
[DeviceFarm] echo "Start Appium TestNG test"
Start Appium TestNG test
[DeviceFarm] java -Dappium.screenshots.dir=$DEVICEFARM_SCREENSHOT_PATH org.testng.TestNG -testjar *-tests.jar -d $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/test-output -verbose 10
[TestNGContentHandler] [WARN] It is strongly recommended to add "<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >" at the top of your file, otherwise TestNG may fail or not work as expected.
[TestNG] RUNNING: Suite: "Test" containing "3" Tests (config: /tmp/testngXmlPathInJar-2609962504057331442/testng.xml)
[TestNG] INVOKING CONFIGURATION: "Test" - @BeforeClass utils.DriverTestCase.InvokeTestSet(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)(value(s): "Local", "Android", "4723")
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-13-65', ip: '172.31.13.65', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-139-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:195)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:209)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:93)
    at utils.DriverTestCase.startServer(DriverTestCase.java:113)
    at utils.DriverTestCase.InvokeTestSet(DriverTestCase.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1354)
    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1323)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:185)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.connectyourcare.mobile30' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: 'crc64b682049863c133e8.SplashActivity' or 'com.connectyourcare.mobile30.crc64b682049863c133e8.SplashActivity' never started. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-13-65', ip: '172.31.13.65', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-139-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.connectyourcare.mobile30' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: 'crc64b682049863c133e8.SplashActivity' or 'com.connectyourcare.mobile30.crc64b682049863c133e8.SplashActivity' never started. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting
    at getResponseForW3CError (/usr/local/avm/versions/1.15.1/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (/usr/local/avm/versions/1.15.1/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:388:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    ... 44 more
[TestNG] PASSED CONFIGURATION: "Test" - @BeforeClass utils.DriverTestCase.InvokeTestSet(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)(value(s): "Local", "Android", "4723") finished in 138085 ms
Start Of Execution(TEST)->Create_A_NewPayment_To_Provider
[TestNG] INVOKING: "Test" - testscripts.TestScript.Create_A_NewPayment_To_Provider()
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: The stack trace says it could not start your application. Have you tried Appium's troubleshooting guide? http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup/